# Which is the best way to refresh an extra variable as long as MATLAB ga optimtool iterates?

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I use the ga MATLAB optimtool to minimize an objective function.

I create two functions in the same script `main.m`.
If I don't use the variable `a` the genetic algorithm
works well. When I introduce the variable `a` calling
it in every iteration `a = fcn( a );` in the `main.m`
then I get an error *Not enough input arguments. (line 5)*

```
%% main function
function [x,fval,a] = main()
nvars = 1;  a = 0; % assign the number of values and the variable a

a = fcn( a,t ); % call the fitness fcn 

[x,fval] = ga(@(t) fcn(t),nvars);

end
%% fitness function
function [ y,a ] = fcn( a,t )
y = abs( t - 1 ); % objective fcn
a = a + 1;
end
```

*I mention that `a` is an extra variable, unrelated to ga's operation.*
I realize that though Ι refresh the value `a` for the first time, I don't 
manage to change `a` as long as the genetic algorithm iterates to find the better value.

Is there any idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: But If `a` changes, then the best fit will change. The objective function should not change during the GA optimization, else you can easily program an objective function that always picks the furthest point after a GA iteration. Additionally, you `a` does nothing but count iterations, do you need to have that in there to count the number of iterations?

Comment: Thank you for your response!! This is why, I'm saying that the variable `a` is unrelated to ga's operation. I  use `a` just to change it. It could be to count the number of iterations. Specifically I am conducting simulations for Genetic Algorithm. The simulation software takes an input parameter (population for ga). I want to change this input in every iteration as long as the ga runs. In every iteration the simulation output will be different depending on variable `a`.

Comment: You need to find another way to count the iterations, because there is no way MATLAB to know that `a` is unrelated, even if it obviously is.

Comment: Do you have any idea about using the variables `funccount` or `generations`? which are outputs of MATLAB. For examples, could it be written something like `a = generations`, `a = a + 1`? May be I obtain this using `generations` as `global` parameter. I'm saying that because `generations` variable changes in every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if your goal is only to count the number of calls `ga` does to your fitness function, you already have access to it via the `output` output of `ga` :

> [x,fval,exitflag,output] = ga(fitnessfcn,nvars,...) returns output, a
>   structure that contains output from each generation and other
>   information about the performance of the algorithm.

When you look at what is in this `output` variable, you directly find :

```
output = 

  problemtype: 'unconstrained'
     rngstate: [1x1 struct]
  generations: 56
    funccount: 2850
      message: 'Optimization terminated: average change in the fit...'
maxconstraint: []
```

And the number of calls to your function can be accessed via a call to `output.funccount`

---

If the question is more about how to update any extra variable in the fitness function, I think your best bet is to use `global` variables :

### Test Script

```
global a

a=0;

[x,fval,output] = main();
```

### `main` function

```
function [x,fval,output] = main()
nvars = 1;  

[x,fval,~,output] = ga(@fcn,nvars);

end
```

### `fcn` function

```
function [ y ] = fcn(t)

global a

y = abs( t - 1 ); % objective fcn
a = a + 1;
end
```

### Outputs

```
output = 

      problemtype: 'unconstrained'
         rngstate: [1x1 struct]
      generations: 100
        funccount: 5050
          message: 'Optimization terminated: maximum number of gener...'
    maxconstraint: []


a =

        5050
```

You can see that `a` is equal to `output.funccount`, meaning it has been refreshed at every `fcn` call